# unable to connect ftp in pasive mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I'm try to connect to ftp which I've just configured but using fileZilla, I'm getting the following logs

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Command:    USER huntsnap
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/my/home/dir"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,38,106,212,248,2).
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I've configured vsftpd on ubuntu server, don't know whats wrong with it.

vsftp.conf File

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
local_root=/home/to/my/home/
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Debian vsftpd config lines related to passive ftp:

```
# Contents of: /etc/vsftpd.conf
pasv_min_port=48900
pasv_max_port=48939
```

And make sure your firewall accepts incoming TCP connections to 48900:48939 range.

Actually you may pick another port range...

Comment: Thanks for replying it really worked, just one thing I've added the port range through web interface of amazon security group, there was no option to only allow those ports in passive mode, how can I make this?

Comment: vsftpd will do that for you, TCP/IP is simple - just open what is needed and the software will catch the traffic because it's bind to those ports.